# Why does the music video of "Living Next Door to Alice" by Smokie seem happy?

Tags: meaning, music-video

The song "Living Next Door to Alice" tells (in my opinion) a bit of a sad story. The protagonist is talking about Alice leaving, how he won't be able to see her again and won't be able to ever tell her about his feelings. Despite that *sadness*, in [the music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6qnRS36EgE), it feels like Smokie is trying to debase it by constantly smiling.

Is this just my opinion, or is the song actually not that sad?

Comment: Beautiful song. Heard it about 50 years ago. Recently a line dance (called ALICE) was choreographed to this song. Lovely steps and very enjoyable as a line dance. Check it out under Dallas 5 dancers.

Comment: We live in the house that belonged to Alice the lead singer of Smokie obviously lived next door she was as far as we understand an elderly lady he befriended who either died or had to go into a care home.

Comment: Alice could not have lived next door to the lead singer of Smokie 1976 (British) as the lyrics were written in Brisbane (Australia) in 1972

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that the song is pretty sad. The narrator/singer is losing his childhood best friend/lifelong crush. I think that qualifies as sad.

That having been said, a lot of songs have music videos (or even instrumentation) that doesn't match the tone or feeling of the lyrics. Just a few examples:

- "[Tears of a Clown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t52YcxbVpOQ)" - Smokey Robinson & the Miracles - Really upbeat song instrumentally, while lyrically it's about the narrator trying to hide how sad he is about a recent break-up.
- "[Hey Ya!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWgvGjAhvIw)" - Outkast - Another (incredibly) upbeat song instrumentally with lyrics that talk vaguely about failed relationships and modern love. The music video is also super high energy, parodying Beatlemania in the 60s.
- "[Cosmic Slop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8vBDET3kbI)" - Funkadelic - The narrator of the song recalls his mother repenting about prostituting herself to support her kids, and the instrumentation matches the lyrics. However, the music video (actually more of a promo video, since there's no lip syncing at all) features the crazily dressed members of the band dancing in New York City.

Those are just ones I was able to think of off the top of my head. [There](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1h8vw5/what_are_some_upbeat_songs_with_very_sad_or/) are a [number](http://www.metrolyrics.com/news-gallery-happy-sounding-songs-that-are-sad.html) of [lists](http://popcrush.com/songs-sound-happy-dark-lyrics/) of [songs](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-sad-sounding-songs-that-have-happy-lyrics) whose [lyrics](http://www.playbuzz.com/jessicak14/18-happy-songs-that-are-actually-very-sad) don't [match](http://www.cracked.com/blog/6-popular-upbeat-songs-you-didnt-realize-are-depressing/) the [instrumentation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/3padk8/whatre_some_happysounding_songs_about_sad_topics/) or [music video](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/4xunym/what_music_video_doesnt_match_the_song_it_was/) in [tone](https://www.bustle.com/articles/85227-11-music-videos-that-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-lyrics-of-their-songs-videos).

Comment: "Pumped Up Kicks" is another great example.  The video gives no clue that it's a song about a school shooter.